# Extending WiFi for an RV

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

We finally found a campground with "free" wifi, but we were just on a far outer reaches of the WAP. I was able to use my [HooToo wifi/battery device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RVIGY1I) and put it in a spot where there was better signal and then setup my own WiFi using the free wifi for the internet. It worked decently.

That got me thinking that I should set up an outdoor antenna on my camper then connect it to a router inside the camper so we have our own Wifi. I know there are external antennas and I am thinking of using a Yagi antenna for a more directional focus. But how do I setup the router? Do I use a range extender that can act as a router? Do I just plug the external antenna to one of the existing antennas connections? Do I use a RaspberryPi and do something with that?

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wm0696W0hQ) that explains roughly what I'm looking for, but I'd like for it to be an all-in-one device or something that is cheaper (aka easier sell to the wife).

Please let me know if this is the wrong forum and I'll post this somewhere else.

Comment: I've built a cantenna that sent old 802.11b over 500 yards until we lost line of sight due to a building....  had it on a 6' cable attached to PCI wireless card in a desktop machine, just dangled it out the window (we have tinted windows that really killed signal)

Answer (score 4):

> But how do I setup the router? Do I use a range extender that can act as a router?

Neither – this has absolutely nothing to do with routing of IP packets.

Conceptually, most home "wireless routers" are 3-in-1 devices: an IP router, an Ethernet (wired LAN) switch, and a Wi-Fi access point. To add more LAN ports, you'd simply connect a second external Ethernet switch to the same router; to expand the Wi-Fi range, you would connect more Wi-Fi APs.

In other words, a you need is a range extender that can act as a *range extender* (i.e. access point), which is all of them.

As far as configuration goes, only the extender/AP itself needs to be configured:

- If you set it to the same SSID and WPA password (but ideally a different channel), then devices will automatically roam to the 'best' AP – which is the most convenient option.
- OTOH, if you have mysterious connection problems, then use different SSIDs. (For example, my home *printer* gets completely confused when it sees the same SSID from two APs...)

(Note: Many people use a 2nd "wireless router" for this purpose, but this usually involves *disabling* the "routing" part in it. Search for older posts on this topic.)

> Do I just plug the external antenna to one of the existing antennas connections?

If the existing router/AP comes with 2 or more antennas, then I would guess that it's optimized for their specific size & distance, and running an external antenna cable off their ports [might be a bad idea.](https://superuser.com/questions/1224986/external-antennas-of-same-router-on-different-floors) (If it has only a single antenna, or a *dedicated* external antenna port, then that has a bigger chance of working, but you should still read the comments on that linked post.)

Though there certainly *are* access points built specifically with that kind of usage in mind – usually sold as "for long-range PtP/PtMP connections". Some models accept an external connection, while others have an internal surface of patch antennas. (In pairs they have a range of many kilometers; when used with plain phones/tablets/laptops they're still generally sensitive enough for at least 250–500 m.)

> Do I use a RaspberryPi and do something with that?

It's possible to configure any Linux system as an access point by installing `hostapd`, as long as the hardware supports it. The "Raspberry Pi 3" can do it, but USB-connected Wi-Fi adapters are *very* hit-or-miss. Running `iw phy` would show whether AP mode is supported.

(Note that an AP / range extender needs *only* `hostapd` bridged to the Ethernet port. Some tutorials tell you to set up dhcpd and/or iptables-masquerade, but you **don't need that** since your existing router already does this.)